# Pulling Select Case data from one sub to another

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Hello all My question is: Is it possible to pull case select data from another sub? I have this in a button sub:

```
    'Public Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles         

btnSearch.Click

Dim strInvalid As String = txtUsername.Text

Dim frmIdenitityCheckerResults As New frmIdenitityCheckerResults()

Select Case True

Case txtUsername.Text = (ReadALine(filename, GetNumberOfLines(filename), 
0))

Me.Close()

My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.TopLevel = False

My.Forms.FrmWorkTool.Panel2.Controls.Add
(My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults)


my.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.Show()

My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.Label2.Text = "John"

My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.lblSSN.Text = "1211"

My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.lblCompany.Text = strPhoenix

My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.lblEMP.Text = "1"

My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.lblStartDate.Text = "10/10/2017"

Case txtUsername.Text = (ReadALine(filename, GetNumberOfLines(filename), 2))

Me.Close()

My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.TopLevel = False

My.Forms.FrmWorkTool.Panel2.Controls.Add
(My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults)

My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.Show()

My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.Label2.Text = "Terri"

My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.lblSSN.Text = "4218"

My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.lblCompany.Text = strPhoenix

My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.lblEMP.Text = "2"

My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.lblStartDate.Text = "10/10/2017"'
Case txtUsername.Text = (ReadALine(filename, GetNumberOfLines(filename), 1))
            Link_lbl1.Text = "John"

Case txtUsername.Text = (ReadALine(filename, GetNumberOfLines(filename), 3)) OrElse
        txtUsername.Text = (ReadALine(filename, GetNumberOfLines(filename), 3)) OrElse
        txtUsername.Text = (ReadALine(filename, GetNumberOfLines(filename), 3)) OrElse
        txtUsername.Text = (ReadALine(filename, GetNumberOfLines(filename), 3))
            Link_lbl1.Text = "Terri"
            Link_lbl2.Text = "Jordan"
            Link_lbl3.Text = "Lisa"
            Link_lbl4.Text = "David"
```

I'm wanting to pull data from this Select Case to input in the code below

```
    Private Sub link_lbl1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles Link_lbl1.LinkClicked

    Select Case 
        Case Link_lbl1.Text = "John"
            btnSearch 1

            Case Link_lbl1.Text = "Terri"
    End Select

End Sub'
```

But I'm unsure if this is a possibility or not if anyone can point me in the right direction It'll be much appreciated.

I attempted:

```
  Select Case link_lbl1.text
  Case "John"
```

But that threw an error and wasn't pulling data from my previous case select.
I can make it work using the below but didn't know if there was an easier way to go about it.

```
Private Sub link_lbl1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As 
LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles Link_lbl1.LinkClicked
    Select Case True
        Case Link_lbl1.Text = "John"
            Me.Close()
            My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.TopLevel = False
            My.Forms.FrmWorkTool.Panel2.Controls.Add(My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults)
            My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.Show()
            My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.Label2.Text = "John"
            My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.lblSSN.Text = "1211"
            My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.lblCompany.Text = strPhoenix
            My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.lblEMP.Text = "1"
            My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.lblStartDate.Text = "10/10/2017"
        Case Link_lbl1.Text = "Terri"
            Me.Close()
            My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.TopLevel = False
            My.Forms.FrmWorkTool.Panel2.Controls.Add(My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults)
            My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.Show()
            My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.Label2.Text = "Terri"
            My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.lblSSN.Text = "4218"
            My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.lblCompany.Text = strPhoenix
            My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.lblEMP.Text = "2"
            My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults.lblStartDate.Text = "10/10/2017"
    End Select
End Sub'
```

Comment: Try `Select Case Link_lbl1.Text` then `Case "John"`

Comment: I'll give that a Shot thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: I updated the code the option you gave me  didn't pull it from the other Select Case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, your `Select Case` is wrong to begin with.  Rather than this:

```
Select Case True
    Case Link_lbl1.Text = "John"
        '...
    Case Link_lbl1.Text = "Terri"
        '...
End Select
```

You should be doing this:

```
Select Case Link_lbl1.Text
    Case "John"
        '...
    Case "Terri"
        '...
End Select
```

As for the question, I assume that what you mean is that you want to avoid repeating yourself in each `Case` block.  If so then the first thing to do is to identify what is common and what is specific.  You can copy the common part into a method and then add a parameter for each specific part, e.g.

```
Private Sub DoSomething(label2Text As String, ssn As String, emp As String)
    With My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults
        .TopLevel = False
        .Show()
        .Label2.Text = label2Text
        .lblSSN.Text = ssn
        .lblCompany.Text = strPhoenix
        .lblEMP.Text = emp
        .lblStartDate.Text = "10/10/2017"
    End With

    My.Forms.FrmWorkTool.Panel2.Controls.Add(My.Forms.frmIdenitityCheckerResults)
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

You can then just call that method in each `Case` block and pass in the appropriate values for each argument.

Note that I have also used a `With` block to neaten up that code and reordered things more appropriately too.

Comment: Ahh I understand now yep that's what I was trying to figure out Thanks a bunch!